# Issue sorting datagrid by dates

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a data grid with dates displayed as Sep-14-2016 format.
I am searching for records with same last name.

I have set of four records with the following dates:  Sep-07-2016, Sep-14-2016, Sep-15-2016, Sep-20-2016

I have a second set of four records with dates Sep-14-2016, Sep-15-2016, Sep-16-2016, Sep-17-2016.

When I sort the first set, all of the records will sort either ASC or Desc.
However, the second set only the first and last record in the set sort.

Same database, datatype and background code.

I am at a loss for why the sorts are not working correctly.

Comment: any code to offer? or do you sort by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizing this is not an answer, but the short of it was a faulty method was being called in an insanely huge and complex code base.

I changed the code to perform the sort as follows

```
long dateLeft = CustomClass.EventDate.DateLong.Value;
long dateRight = CustomClass.EventDate.DateLong.Value;
return dateLeft.CompareTo(dateRight);
public int CompareTo(Int64 value) {

        if (m_value < value) return -1; 
        if (m_value > value) return 1; 
        return 0;
    }
```

EventDate is a parameter in my class and m_value is a declared internal long.  It was originally using a custom class on the Date, that apparently needs some tweaking.